# When I select the program the textarea is appended but the word counter is not working? what is my fault?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

Word counter not working on this appended text area, please suggest some solutions

I have used laravel 8 and javascript

```
function countChar(param) {
    crow = $(param).parent().parent();
    var des = $(crow).find('#professional_statement').val();
    console.log(des);
    var count = 0;
    var split = des.split(' ');
    for (var i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
        if (split[i] != "") {
            count++;
        }
    }
    if (count < 301) {
        $("#enablesavebtn").hide();
        $(crow).find('#charNum1').css("color", "red");
        $(crow).find('#charNum1').text(count);

    } else if (split > 501) {
        $(crow).find('#charNum1').text(count);
        $("#enablesavebtn").show();
        $(crow).find('#charNum1').css("color", "green");
    } else {
        $(crow).find('#charNum1').text(0 + count);
        $("#enablesavebtn").show();
        $(crow).find('#charNum1').css("color", "green");
    }

};
```

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  if (data[i]['program_category'] != 'Professional') {
    var purpose_statement = '';
    // if (data.length - 1) {

            
    var wcounter = '<p><span id="charNum1">0</span> Word out of <b id="charNum">500</b></p>';
    // }

    if (data[i]["purpose_statement"] == 'null') { purpose_statement = ""; } else { purpose_statement = data[i]["purpose_statement"] }
    $('#ProfessionalStatementContainer').append(`<label class="mb-0">Purpose statement for ` + data[i]["program_category"] + `</label> <div class="form-row mt-1">
      <div class="form-group col-12 col-md-12 mb-2">
      <input type="hidden" value="` + data[i]["program_id"] + `" name="app_prog_id[]">
      <textarea onkeyup="countChar(this)" class="form-control" min="2700" max="3500" minlength="2700" maxlength="3500" rows="5" id="professional_statement" name="professional_statement[]" placeholder="Enter text here">` + purpose_statement + `</textarea>
      ` + wcounter + `
    
      </div>
      </div>`);
  } else {
    $('#ProfessionalStatementContainer').append(`<label class="mb-0">Purpose statement for ` + data[i]["program_category"] + `</label>`);
    //$('.profess_summ_instruction').hide();
    $('#ProfessionalStatementContainer').append('<p class="mb-3">Professional summary is not required for professional category</p>');
    }
  }
```

[image: when i select program then textarea append in 2nd image]

[image: apended teaxtarea but word counter not working]

Comment: Compare the if with the else if.  Ask yourself what is `count` and what is `split`

Comment: You're using for loop as a solution to double spaces? Have you ever heard about `Array#filter`? Did you try adding more console.log to see if `#charNum1` is found? any other errors in developer console?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, if count < 300 or count > 500, it wil hide the save button and show the error with red text. So I think the code should be:

```
if (count < 300 || count > 500) {
        $("#enablesavebtn").hide();
        $(crow).find('#charNum1').css("color", "red");
        $(crow).find('#charNum1').text(count);
    } else {
        $(crow).find('#charNum1').text(0 + count);
        $("#enablesavebtn").show();
        $(crow).find('#charNum1').css("color", "green");
    }
```